# Populate NSComboBox with something other than an array of Strings

Tags: swift, cocoa

I have an array of objects of a class derived from `NSObject` in Swift that I would like to add to a `NSComboBox`.

**For example :**

```
class MyItem : NSObject 
{
   var data = "Hello"
   var value = 1.234
}


var listOfItems = [MyItem]();

var item1 = MyItem()
var item2 = MyItem()

listOfItems.append( item1)
listOfItems.append( item2)

myNSComboBox.addItemsWithObjectValues(listOfItems)
```

Is there something I can add to or override in `MyItem` that will return a string to be displayed in the `NSComboBox`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array of strings with the appropriate strings in it.

```
func transform(sequence: [MyItem], inout output: [String], pred: (MyItem) -> String) {
    var g = sequence.generate()
    while let obj = g.next() {
        output.append(pred(obj))
    }
}


var listOfItems: [String] = []
transform(listOfItems, &listOfItems) {
    $0.data
}

myNSComboBox.addItemsWithObjectValues(listOfItems)
```

The transform function above can be made into a generic function that will work for any sequence type. I will leave that as an exercise for the reader. :-)